# How does checking the Build Version Code work in Android?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

How can checking the build version code work on older devices?

For example, say you are on Honeycomb (v11), and you run this method:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void doSomething(){

  // bla bla bla ....
  ...

   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) // Jelly_Bean is v16)
   {
     addNotificationActions(builder);
   }

}
```

How would the OS know what Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN is? The Android Lint checker doesn't report any errors here. Perhaps this is resolved at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would the OS know what Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN is?

Because that is a `static final int`. Your compiled Java code contains the integer value, not the symbol. Hence, at runtime, the `if` statement is comparing against the compiled-in integer value.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks